# How to check if Object exist before executing foreach loop in java8

Tags: java

I have some input files which contains some number. And if filter found that number vulnerable, it removes that.
For example, in the filter, I have defined that if the file contains 2,45,600, please remove that.
If a text file contains 2,23,4,45,600- filter removes those numbers and returns a boolean value and in the foreach loop, I can see the result.
But if a file contains 45,600, then foreach loop returns nothing.

```
takeInputPath().flatMap(readFile::read).filter(filterIds()) // filterIds() returns true  or 
          //false
            .forEach(txtoutput -> System.out.println(txtoutput)); // this foreach loop 
               //sometimes 
               //returns value(if some ids are present) and 
                // sometimes does not return anything if all values get filtered out
```

So, before foreach loop, I want to put some conditions to see, if the files exist or not. If it does not exist, then will log that message.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a local `boolean` array with one element to store whether or not the stream contained any elements that were printed. The array is necessary because lambdas and anonymous inner classes can only use effectively final local variables.

```
final boolean[] hasElements = {false};
takeInputPath().flatMap(readFile::read).filter(filterIds())
            .forEach(txtoutput -> {hasElements[0] = true; System.out.println(txtoutput);}); 
//hasElements[0] is now true if any elements were in the stream after filtering
```

Comment: Can you specify the goal behavior more precisely?  Are you wanting to collect the boolean values of numbers (in the file) which are not forbidden?  For example, if { 2, 3, 5, 7 } are forbidden and the boolean function is "isIntegerSquare", then { 2, 5 } would yield a null result and { 2, 4, 6, 7 } would yield { true (4 is an integer square), false (6 is not an integer square }.

Comment: @ThomasBitonti `hasElements[0]` is just used as a flag to indicate whether or not the stream had elements that were printed.